# Selenium - search within a List<String> with another String[] or List<String>

Tags: java, selenium

I'm a newbie when it comes to Selenium automation testing.
Here's my problem

```
public void verifyItemsAreDisplayed(String columnname, String[] columntosearch) {
       boolean ispresent = false;
       List<string> colitems = getRowData(columnname); // this is getting all text from specific column of a grid using gettext
       for (String item: colitemstosearch) {
            for(String all: colitems) {
                 if (item.contains(all) {
                      system.out.println(item + " is displayed.");
                      ispresent = true;
                      break;
                 }
                 if(!ispresent) {
                      system.out.println(item + " is not displayed.";
                      break;
                 }
            }
      }
 }
```

This is the call method I use:

```
String[] values = {"Not Started", "In Progress", "Complete"}
test.verifyItemsAreDisplayed("ID", values);
```

Expected output:

```
getRowData method output :

Column name: ID
Row Size: 6
> In Progress
> In Progress
> Not Started
> Complete
> Complete
> Not Started

verifyItemsAreDisplayed method output :

Not Started is displayed.
In Progress is displayed.
Complete is displayed.
```

What I got :

```
getRowData method output :

Column name: ID
Row Size: 6
> In Progress
> In Progress
> Not Started
> Complete
> Complete
> Not Started

verifyItemsAreDisplayed method output :

Not Started is NOT displayed.
In Progress is displayed.
```

The other string that i used to search: Complete are not displayed in the output whether it's in the list or not.

Anyone what went wrong with my code ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three changes:

- Move the declaration of `ispresent` to just before the inner loop, so its value is reset for every item being checked
- Move the check for `ispresent` until *after* checking *all* the items - ie *outside* the inner loop (and delete the `break` therein)
- Fix the numerous spelling/syntax errors preventing your posted code from compiling

```java
public void verifyItemsAreDisplayed(String columnname, String[] columntosearch) {
    List<string> colitems = getRowData(columnname);
    for (String item : colitemstosearch) {
        boolean ispresent = false;
        for (String all : items) {
            if (item.contains(all) {
                System.out.println(item + " is displayed.");
                ispresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!ispresent) {
            System.out.println(item + " is not displayed.";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh stupid me, the answer to my problem is simple. I'm sorry for some mistype text because i just copied it word by word to another computer haha. Anyways, my problem is solved now. Thank you!!